# strategies for looking at the phase space of a system with 6 dimensions

Tags: dynamical-systems, biology, principal-component-analysis

I have a system of odes where the state vector has 6 elements. The system is a population biology model, where I am tracking the evolution of some competing species over time.

Now I was trying to think about how to look at the phase space for this system? Since this is a 6 dimensional system, that is like $\binom{6}{2}$ combinations.

My sense is that I should apply some dimensional reduction method. So I could do this in a couple of ways. First, I could use Principal Components Analysis (PCA) and then plot the first 2 or 3 components--assuming that they capture a suitably large percentage of the variation. The second choice would be to use something like an autoencoder to essentially learn a good transformation of the data into 2 or 3 coordinates, and then map those. There are of course some variations on these methods, like robust PCA, or kernel PCA, etc., which I can experiment with.

I just wanted to make sure that my approach was correct here. Given that I can't look at the full dynamics in 6 dimensions at once, is this projection method the best approach? Should I be concerned about missing some dynamics or multiscale time-scale information when I do this kind of reduction?

Comment: I think what you suggested sounds very reasonable. However, regardless of whatever method you use, what you would end up with is an approximation of the original system. This means you would lose some properties (hopefully not key properties) of the system. Alternatively, I'd like to just plot all phase plots of 2 variables (since you have 6, that would be 15 plots). Besides the methods that you proposed, quasi-steady state-type arguments can also be used to reduce model dimension (from an analytical perspective).

Comment: @Paichu Oh thanks for the comment. Very helpful. Yeah, I can plot all of the phase diagrams too--the system is small enough that I can do that. Can you explain the quasi-steady-state idea a bit more. I think I have seen them do this in economics, where they basically find a function for the optimal value, and then substitute that optimal function into other functions. In that case then I would not need to plot that phase plots include that optimal function--because I can assume it stays fixed. Is that what you mean, or am I misinterpreting?